# Solving Laplace equation on a triangle with mixed boundary conditions

Tags: boundary-conditions, eigenvalue, differential-equations

From sources [Ref: 1 to 5], one learns that there is a class of boundary conditions (see Fig 1) on a triangle (in this case the 30-60-90 triangle) that allow for closed form solution for eigensystems of Laplace equation (or time independent Helmholtz equation or even Schrodinger equation). Solid lines represent fixed boundaries, dashed lines represent free boundaries.

[image: Fig 1 - Solid lines represent fixed boundaries, dashed lines represent free boundaries.]

However one also learns that there exist no closed form solutions for the other class of boundary conditions (Fig 2). Solid lines represent fixed boundaries, dashed lines represent free boundaries.

[image: Fig 2 - Solid lines represent fixed boundaries, dashed lines represent free boundaries.]

Question 1: I want to understand whether there is a fundamental reason for why some boundary conditions would not have a closed form solution - is there any intuition for that?

This further extends to the fact that one would not have a closed form expression for eigenvalues which among other things makes some analysis difficult which involve finding **accidental degeneracies** (I am interested in accidental degeneracies of order >=3). In Ref:3 the author makes a statement about accidental degeneracies might not exist for the non-closed solutions. Stemming from this fact, one would not be able to analytically solve for all eigenfunctions of Laplace equation on a Hexagon (say example with fixed boundaries)among other shapes that result from tiling such triangles in a certain fashion. Ref:4 remarks that one cannot even find the analytic expression for the fundamental mode of the Hexagon - Fig 3 was obtained numerically.

[image: Fig 3 - Fundamental mode of Hexagon with fixed boundaries]

References:

1. http://www.m-hikari.com/mccartin-3.pdf
2. https://www.hbelabs.com/phd/thesis.pdf
3. https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01519629v5/document
4. NOTE ON THE VIBRATION OF MEMBRANES, D. G. Christopherson (Oxford), 1939
5. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11431-008-0348-6
6. https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01718768/file/berard-helffer-ecp-II-balslev-190926-ha.pdf

Note 1:
By fixed boundary I mean (throughout this question) that eigenfunctions are identically zero at the specified boundaries (solid lines) - Dirichlet condition. Sometimes one may refer the above condition as clamped boundaries.
While free boundaries here mean that the normal derivative of the eigenfunction is identically zero on the specified boundary (dashed lines) - Neumann condition.

Note 2:
Degeneracies can be classified as geometric or accidental (see example https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/7/13/008/pdf). Geometric degeneracies occur due to the symmetry of the system. Accidental degeneracies occur in principle due to number theory reasons.

Comment: What do you mean fixed and free boundaries? One normally specifies the function value, it's derivative, or can do a combination of both.

Comment: I have added this in the note. Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I've voted to migrate this to the [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) because I think it would be much more at home there.

Comment: @ChitresGuria you may want to look at the Fokas method. 
 usually the global relation helps inform you as to why certain boundary conditions will/won't work.   https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40315-013-0038-7